# I need to help about Ubuntu MAAS Architecture in My Scenario

Tags: maas

I educate about Ubuntu MAAS a while, So I have plan my architecture and I have many question about MAAS
Domain: zanroo.zone registered on GoDaddy
Region Controller on High Availability
Server1: on EC2
Server2: on Google Compute
Server3: on Digital Ocean
Q1: but I have Region more than one,what do I need to set DNS Server a few machine for can controller all rack controller?

Rack Controller over Softlayer Bare Metal Server
Q2: After Install Rack Controller and Connect to Region Controller via Secret Key, I need to do anything?

I hope someone can help me. Thx
This is my first question.